# displaying email address in browser with razor asp.net

Tags: asp.net, razor

I would like to display `"me@mymail.com"` at the browser. I know it's unsafe to display email address like that. So, when we view source it appear as a javascript.Is this possible with razor. I use to work like that with codeigniter php framework `safe_email()` when displaying email address in browser.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking for, but try to put it like: me%40mymail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact you're using Razor is irrelevant. The only way to keep email addresses safe from address harvesters is to obfuscate it in the page, then use client-scripting to deobfuscate it for appropriate clients. I like to use human-readable obfuscation as not to lock-out users with scripting disabled. This is what I do (using MVC WebForms syntax):

```
String emailAddress = "name@example.com";

public static String Escape(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(Char c in s) {
        sb.Append('%');
        Int32 ic = (Int32)c;
        String hex = ic.ToString("X2"); // convert to hexadecimal
        sb.Append( hex );
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

<span id="email"><%= Html.Encode( emailAddress.Replace("@", "REMOVE@CAPITALIZED") ) %></span>

<script type="text/ecmascript">
    document.getElementById("email").innerText = unescape("<%= Escape( emailAddress ) %>" );
</script>
```

Escaping text shields them from harvesters, but the script will automatically reveal it in any competent browser. Users without scripts will see a human-readable obfuscated address which they can trivially correct themselves.

Comment: can this be used making helpers in web pages ?

Comment: Yeah, you could make the `Escape` function a HtmlHelper, but you'd need to think of something smarter for the escape client script.